# How to disable the top menu blinking when a keyboard shortcut is used in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm using Mac OS X Lion. When I press a keyboard shortcut, the corresponding item in the top menu gets blue background for a brief moment and then returns back to it's default gray background. It somewhat irritates me. Is there a way to disable this blinking?

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to get used to that. It's always been like this and it's core OS functionality.

Comment: No, because it's not actually "blinking". The menu is being selected by the shortcut, and that's what you're seeing.

Comment: Not only is that a core OS feature, it's been that way since the OS 9 days, possibly as far back as OS 7.  While the blinking is annoying, it's a handy way to indicate to a user where the keyboard shortcut they just executed can be found by menu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- If `Blue` is the problem, and a darker greyish `Graphite` would do the job for you and won't irritate you as much, you go to `System Preferences`, click on `General`, and change the appearance from `Blue` to `Graphite`. It's more towards the default `Grey` you want, but a little darker. Attaching a screenshot of the same.
- In System Preferences

[image: General]

- How it actually looks

[image: Actual]

- If this is not what you want, and disabling it or making it a transparent highlight is what your looking for, then you might have to wait till [ShapeShifter](http://www.unsanity.com/haxies/shapeshifter) is made compatible for OSX Lion.
- Or you can hack OSX by going to this path and figuring out how to manipulate the XML in this folder: 
  `/System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIToolbox.framework/Versions/A/Resources/English.lproj/`.  Since these files help us edit the menu options, there has to be an option to enhance the highlighting on the MenuBar also.
- You will need Xcode to do this ofcourse, but at your own risk!

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to change the background graphic on Mountain Lion, but it also removes the highlight when menus are clicked manually. And I don't know how to change the text color.

[image]

1. Compile [sartFileTool](https://github.com/alexzielenski/sartFileTool) or download [a complied binary](http://www60.zippyshare.com/v/7117646/file.html)
2. `cp /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreUI.framework/Resources/SArtFile.bin ~/Desktop/original.bin`
3. `sartFileTool -d ~/Desktop/original.bin ~/Desktop/art`
4. Make 49-1.png (or 49-2.png for HiDPI modes) transparent
5. `sartFileTool -e ~/Desktop/art ~/Desktop/new.bin`
6. `sudo cp ~/Desktop/new.bin /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreUI.framework/Resources/SArtFile.bin`
7. Open a new application or reopen some application

A few graphics were also drawn incorrectly after I replaced the SArtFile.bin.

[image]

Adding a key for NSMenuItemHighlightColor to .GlobalPreferences.plist didn't work. I tried changing some attributes in [Extras2.rsrc](http://web.archive.org/web/20110624120642/http://macthemes.net/wiki/Extras.rsrc) with [ThemePark 3.1](http://www.geekspiff.com/software/themepark/), but it didn't seem to have any effect either.

There's another question about [changing the selection color at Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/25802/how-do-i-change-the-lion-menubar-selection-color).